# How is inlining more efficeny than recursive definition?

Tags: language-agnostic, scheme, inline, paradigms

My Programming Paradigms textbook, [Essential of Programming Languages (3rd ed)](http://personal.stevens.edu/%7Ewkhokhar/files/Friedman%20-%20Essentials%20of%20Programming%20Languages%203e%20%28MIT,%202008%29.pdf), Chapter 1 has an exercise:

> Exercise 1.12
>
> Eliminate the one call to subst-in-s-exp in subst by
> replacing it by its definition and simplifying the resulting
> procedure. The result will be a version of subst that does not need
> subst-in-s-exp. This technique is called inlining, and is used by
> optimizing compilers.

The original code would have two functions: `subst` and `subst-in-sexp` which basically substitutes the all occurrences of old symbol with new symbol in the input list.

```
(define subst
  (lambda (new old slist)
    (if (null? slist) '()
        (cons
         (subst-in-s-exp new old (car slist))
         (subst new old (cdr slist))))))

(define subst-in-s-exp
  (lambda (new old sexp)
    (if (symbol? sexp)
        (if (eqv? sexp old) new sexp)
        (subst new old sexp))))
```

The answer to this question is to eliminate `subst-in-sexp`, which becomes this

```
(define subst
  (lambda (slist old new)
    (cond
      [ (null? slist) '()]
      [ (eqv? (car slist) old) (cons new (subst (cdr slist) old new))]
      [ else (cons (car slist) (subst (cdr slist) old new))])))
```

Why is in-lining better besides it may be a lot shorter (less space)? Does the size of the recursion changes? In other words, does this inlining creates fewer stack elements?

Moreover, how can I use this idea to make my C++, Python, and Java code faster? Can I extend this idea easily? Thanks.

I tagged this in Scheme (actually, Racket) because this is the choice of language in the book.

Comment: Yes it should reduce overhead by few stack frames, however this is not really an issue nowadays, code readability matters more and compiler will likely optimize it into something else entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Inlining is a pretty standard compiler optimization, but as AoeAoe said, it's generally better to write your code so that it's readable and let the compiler do all the inlining for you.

The immediate benefit of inlining is that it eliminates branches in your code. It means your CPU can keep reading straight down your code rather than having to spend a couple of clock cycles finding the next section of code to execute.

However, inlining has some other benefits as well. You end up with bigger chunks of code, which means the compiler has more code and data to play with. It might be able to stick more things in registers, or do constant folding to eliminate more computations. The compiler can also do a better job of instruction scheduling, because it has more instructions to move around.

The drawback is that inlining increases your resulting code size. Especially with modern CPUs running so much faster than memory, it can often be better to inline less code in order to keep all of a hot section of code in L1 cache.

Answer (score 3):

Adding just a bit to Eric's answer, inlining can be a big win in dynamically typed languages, where inlining a call may make it possible for a compiler to specialize the implementation to the kinds of data that appear.

For instance: suppose I have a function called f:

```
(define (f x) (+ (* x x) 3.0))
```

... and I call it inline:

```
(+ (f 3.2) (g 3.9))
```

In this case, the inlined code makes it clear that the multiplication and addition can't be called with non-numbers, so this error check can be elided.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to: "How can I use this idea to make my C++, Python, and Java code faster?"

I don't think that the Python runtime does things like automatically inlining small methods. (If this is wrong, someone please correct me!) So in Python, if you have a piece of code which is *very* performance-sensitive, perhaps running tens of thousands or millions of times in an inner loop, you could try inlining manually. *Only* do this if the code is really a bottleneck, and it really needs to be as fast as possible, and always measure to see if such optimizations are actually helping anything. (If you try inlining something and it doesn't help, it's better to undo the optimization, because inlining will generally make your code harder to read.)

In Java and C++, any good compiler will inline small methods for you. The thing which you *can* (sometimes) do, is help the compiler see that a method *can* be inlined. If the exact method which is called depends on the run-time type of an object (as when using `virtual` methods in C++), the compiler will not be able to inline the call. `static` methods in Java can easily be inlined, and declaring methods as `final` (when it makes sense to do so) may also make it possible for the compiler to inline.

If you learn more in the future about compilers and how they work, you will better be able to see how to write performance-sensitive code in a way that the compiler is able to optimize for you.